# mongos returns empty collection when queried from different applications

Tags: mongodb, sharding

We use sharded MongoDB configuration with 2 shards. There are several front applications, which retrieve data via [mongos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongos/) service (installed on each application server).

Problem is that at some point running the same query from Application server #1 will return empty collection, while running the same query from Application server #3 will return correct results.

The problem persists on Application server #1 until [flush](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/flushRouterConfig/) command is run. As documentation states:

> "You should only need to run flushRouterConfig after movePrimary has
>   been run or after manually clearing the jumbo chunk flag."

But neither Primary was moved nor was flag cleared.

Any ideas why could this happen?

**Config file**

```
# mongos.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: false
  logRotate: rename
  path: /var/log/mongos.log

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongos.pid  # location of pidfile

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,94.130.167.133,192.168.0.1  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.

security:
  keyFile: /var/lib/database/mongos/.keyfile

sharding:
  configDB: myproject-config/192.168.0.15:27027,192.168.0.16:27017,192.168.0.17:27017
```

**printShardingStatus()**

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.8
connecting to: cron0.myproject.smapps.org:27017/test
config.locks collection empty or missing. be sure you are connected to a mongos
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("2c5bc3fd9b2385s9613b0la5")
}
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "myproject0",  "host" : "myproject0/192.168.0.11:27017,192.168.0.12:27017",  "state" : 1,  "tags" : [ ] }
    {  "_id" : "myproject1",  "host" : "myproject1/192.168.0.13:27017,192.168.0.18:27017",  "state" : 1,  "tags" : [ "game" ] }
    {  "_id" : "myproject2",  "host" : "myproject2/192.168.0.26:27017,192.168.0.28:27017",  "state" : 1,  "tags" : [ "game" ] }
  active mongoses:
    "4.0.6" : 14
  balancer:
    Currently enabled:  yes
    Currently running:  no
    Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
    Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
        8 : Success
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "myproject",  "primary" : "myproject0",  "partitioned" : true,  "version" : {  "uuid" : BinData(4,"+YxjwrKzTuekDlKutwT1IA=="),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
...
```

Comment: Could provide more information ?
Config files!

Comment: And result of db.printShardingStatus()  comand !

Comment: Added config and printShardingStatus()

Comment: 1.Try to change cnuksize ! for example 1mb. 

2.In testing purposes invoke cycle
for(var i=0; i<100000; i++){
    db.users.insert({“username”: “user”+i, “created at” : new    Date()})
    }
sh.status()
Monitor status of chunks. After this start a balancer and monitor status!

sh.startBalancer() 
sh.status()